# Improving this url with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL I want to shorten with a mod_rewrite.

In its ugliest form it looks like:

```
/img.php?i=15&a=92
```

Ideally it would look like:

```
/img/15/92
```

The problem is sometimes it might just be:

```
/img.php?i=15
```

In which case the person will enter:

```
/img/15
```

So I'm thinking I need a mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*)/(.*)$ /img.php?i=$1&a=$2
```

Which I imagine will work only when both variables are in the URL and not just the shortened version.

How do I make a single rewrite that works for both, or how do I make 2 without cancelling the other out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ img.php?i=$1&a=$3
```

When using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file, you need to remove the per-directory path prefix from the pattern (in this case the leading `/`). Because mod_rewrite does that too and puts back it after the rewrite process.

Comment: I have no idea how you go from $1 to $3 without a $2 - but it works. legend Gumbo

Comment: @cosmicbdog: The second group is the optional one `(…)?` that contains the third group.